# toolbar with dynamic content

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar, datatemplate

**Summary**

How do I add a placeholder in my `Toolbar` so that I could dynamically change its content?

**Detail**

The `Toolbar` in my application shows a dropdown. Depending upon the current selection in the dropdown, I need to select what other items will be shown in the `Toolbar`. So I went ahead and added the dropdown, followed by a `ContentControl`, whose content I dynamically select using a `TemplateSelector`.

This setup works fine except that the `Toolbar` treats the entire `ContentControl` as a single item and moves it to overflow panel if there isn't enough space to display **all of it**. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Notice how it doesn't display any of the `ContentControl` contents even though there is enough space to display at least the first 5 elements.

Note: I have tried it with wrapping my items inside `ToolBarOverflowPanel` too, but that doesn't do any good. I think I understand why it behaves this way, but need a way around it. I have also tried using `WrapPanel` instead of `ContentControl`, but `WrapPanel` doesn't support templating.